# order mysql results by most common values

Tags: mysql

is there a way to order data based on how frequently values appear in mysql columns and also make them `DISTINCT`. So if there was a color column in a table like this:

```
colors
------ ----
red   |
blue  | 
red   |
green |
blue  |
red   |
yellow|
blue  |
green |
red   |
```

the results would be:

```
red
blue
green
yellow
```

as red appeared 4 times, blue 3 times green twice and yellow once. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to *group* your records, then sort on a suitable [aggregate function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/group-by-functions.html):

```
SELECT colors FROM my_table GROUP BY colors ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/90335/1/0).

Comment: excellent. Thanks very much. never even knew there was an sqlfiddle :)

Answer (score 1):

Use a grouped/counted query:

```
SELECT color, count(color) AS cnt
FROM colors
GROUP BY color
ORDER BY cnt DESC
```